# Is there a way in react to tell if it is react native or web?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a bunch of react components that I'm hoping I can use for both web and native.  The way I am trying to do that is like so:

```
React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function(){
        return {isMobile: <some way of tell is native or web>};
    },
    render: function(){
        if(this.state.isMobile){
            return <SomeIosComponent/>
        }
        else{
            return <div/>
        }
    }
});
```

I'd like to be able to do this so I can keep the logic the same for something that appears to be the same on web and native, is this possible? Could it be as simple as `{isMobile: (window ? false : true)}`? Or does window exist in native so there is a way to define globals within a local scope for some odd reason?

I know this goes against the React philosophy of "Learn once, write anywhere".

Comment: Perhaps I'm missing something, but wouldn't your code need to know at a higher level since you need to include 'react-native' or 'react' but not both

Comment: I could do that at build time with gulp.  Although I guess I could also have it require files that just have the components that are named the same and just added at build time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like you said, this goes against the React philosophy, so I wouldn't recommend it.

However, there is a way to determine which `React` you're using if you really want to use this method. This might feel a bit hacky, but React Native has many properties that React does not. So when you write your components, you can check if `React.View` exists. If it does, you're using React Native. Otherwise, you're using the web version.

```
React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function(){
        return {isMobile: React.View !== undefined };
    },
    render: function(){
        if(this.state.isMobile){
            return <SomeIosComponent/>
        }
        else{
            return <div/>
        }
    }
});
```